# jquery autocomplete with external json source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete function that was working with a local json source. Given that it's 16k lines of code, I want to move this to an external json file. However I can't seem to get it working with the external source file. Can anyone point me in the right direction? At the moment this code does not work, but also does not return any errors to the console.

Autocomplete script

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "javascripts/airports.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(request, response) {
             var data = $.grep(suggestion, function(value) {
               return value.city.substring(0, request.term.length).toLowerCase() == request.term.toLowerCase();
             });
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  minLength: 1,
  source: data,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
              $('#autocomplete').val(ui.item.city,ui.item.country);
              return false;
    },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#autocomplete').val(ui.item.name);
      return false;
      }
      }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
          .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.city + "," + item.country + "</a>" )
              .appendTo( ul );
          };
        }
    });
  });
```

External data structure

```
var suggestion =
  [
  {"id":"1","name":"Goroka","city":"Goroka","country":"Papua New Guinea","iata":"GKA","icao":"AYGA","latitude":"-6.081689","longitude":"145.391881","altitude":"5282","timezone":"10","dst":"U","tz":"Pacific/Port_Moresby"}
  ,
  {"id":"2","name":"Madang","city":"Madang","country":"Papua New Guinea","iata":"MAG","icao":"AYMD","latitude":"-5.207083","longitude":"145.7887","altitude":"20","timezone":"10","dst":"U","tz":"Pacific/Port_Moresby"}
  ,
  {"id":"3","name":"Mount Hagen","city":"Mount Hagen","country":"Papua New Guinea","iata":"HGU","icao":"AYMH","latitude":"-5.826789","longitude":"144.295861","altitude":"5388","timezone":"10","dst":"U","tz":"Pacific/Port_Moresby"}
  ,
  {"id":"4","name":"Nadzab","city":"Nadzab","country":"Papua New Guinea","iata":"LAE","icao":"AYNZ","latitude":"-6.569828","longitude":"146.726242","altitude":"239","timezone":"10","dst":"U","tz":"Pacific/Port_Moresby"}
  ,
  {"id":"5","name":"Port Moresby Jacksons Intl","city":"Port Moresby","country":"Papua New Guinea","iata":"POM","icao":"AYPY","latitude":"-9.443383","longitude":"147.22005","altitude":"146","timezone":"10","dst":"U","tz":"Pacific/Port_Moresby"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response should be a JSON object (array) where each item is an object with `id`, `label` and `value` keys.

The items in your `json` files doesn't have the `label` and `value` keys, so the autocomplete can't really show them.

Best solution - change the content of the file/response to follow the `id/label/value` structure.

If you can't do this - you can use the `_renderItem` function to create your own items in the autocomplete based on the content of the json file:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    ...
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( item.name )
            .appendTo( ul );
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: But the json was working when it was being pulled in as a local source. Do you have a rationale as to why the structure of the data would need to change just because it's external?

Comment: To tell you the truth I'm not so sure how it worked, as the structure is not something that should work with the default jquery-ui's autocomplete...